# Meaning of "I thou thee"?

Tags: meaning, archaicisms, thou-thee-thy

What is the meaning of "thou thee" from the quotation below referenced in this [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/English-language-Why-did-people-stop-using-thee-thou-hath-shalt-thy-etc-in-writing)? (Attributed to the [attorney-general at Sir Walter Raleigh’s trial](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Life_of_Sir_Walter_Raleigh_founded_on_au/o8QEAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22i%20thou%20thee%22).)

> All that he did was at thy instigation, thou  viper; for I thou thee, thou traitor.

Comment: The source to which you link also has a complete explanation.  Put the quotation in a Google search box to find it. https://www.quora.com/For-I-thou-thee-thou-traitor-what-does-this-mean

Comment: @Xanne It is a different page of the same domain, but yes it does, thanks.

Comment: The answer given--that thou is being used as a verb--is right on.  And we may move right on, whether this is closed or not.

Comment: @Fattie - Because the OP didn't read the reference he used.

Comment: @Fattie - If you think it's bad here you should see Skeptics.

Comment: @Layrel Typo for Quora.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In "I thou thee", "thou" is a verb. The relevant definition in the OED is:

> *trans*. To address (a person) with the pronoun *thou* (or its equivalent in another language).

(The quote in your question is one of the examples listed for this sense, in fact.)

It's really the same pattern as ["Don't 'honey' me!"](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q2N6mvt5YsgC) which you may have actually heard in real life.

To understand the reason this was an insult, one must be aware that "thou" at this time was a familiar pronoun of the second person singular while "you", the plural, had come to be used in the singular for people owed a certain measure of respect. (Compare French "tu" and "vous", if you're familiar with French.) Therefore, to "thou" someone whose relationship to the speaker would ordinarily call for the use of "you" was a show of grave disrespect.

Comment: For more background, see [T-V distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T–V_distinction).

Comment: @Mark - all these years, I had no idea of the term for that. Thanks!  T–V distinction.

Comment: A brief note: "thou" was not just used for close/intimate/familiar acquaintances, it was *also* used for someone in a subordinate position (e.g. a servant, a lower class of noble, etc).  It's literally a way of saying "you are beneath me/inferior to me".

Answer (score 7):

The comparison with French has been made:

> (thou) *Tu* es une vipère. En effet je *te* *tutoie*, *tu* es un traître!

> (you) *Vous* êtes une vipère. En effet je *vous* *vouvoie*, *vous* êtes un traître!

But you may also compare with German:

> (thou) *Du* Schlange! Ich *duze* *dich*, *du* Verräter!

> (you) *Sie* Schlange! Ich *sieze* *Sie*, *Sie* Verräter!

The cool thing with French and German is that you can explicitly see that they actually have a **verb** for saying "thou" as opposed to "you".

> The verb for "thou" ("*tu*" in French, "*du*" in German): "**tutoyer**" in French and "**duzen**" in German.

> The verb for "you" ("*vous*" in French, "*Sie*" in German): "**vouvoyer**" in French and "**siezen**" in German.

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please. And OP seeks meaning in English.

Comment: @lbf - I think this is a useful answer here -- the French and German phrases are translations of the sentence which involves a concept that is not readily expressible in modern English but which is still commonplace in those languages, so for anyone who is familiar with either of them it is probably the best way of understanding it.

Comment: The French sentence should read *je **te** tutoie*, not *je **vous** tutoie*.

Comment: @jlliagre +1   And similarly the German should be "Ich sage dir du...".

Comment: I think German also has a verb, "duzen", for "saying 'du' to"; so the example could be "Ich duze dich ...".

Comment: I've edited the posted.